# Problems with API upon setting up Express JS on my ReactJS project

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I am working on a little project here and I ran into an issue after hooking up "register" and "login".

I did this through NodeJS with Express.

The error I am having is:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'api' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.
```

That appears in the console whenever I try to fetch the products from the API. I do not get this error if I haven't logged in to an account, but if I have logged in to an account that happens.

Here is my Nodejs code:

```
const express = require("express");
const mysql = require("mysql");
const cors = require("cors");

const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const session = require("express-session");

const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");

const saltRounds = 10;

const app = express();

app.use(
  cors({
    origin: ["http://localhost:3000"],
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
    credentials: true,
  })
);

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(
  session({
    key: "",
    secret: "",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {
      expires: 60 * 60 * 24,
    },
  })
);

app.use(express.json());

const db = mysql.createConnection({
  user: "",
  host: "",
  password: "",
  database: "",
});

app.post("/register", (req, res) => {
  const firstName = req.body.firstName;
  const lastName = req.body.lastName;
  const username = req.body.username;
  const phone = req.body.phone;
  const password = req.body.password;
  const email = req.body.email;

  bcrypt.hash(password, saltRounds, (err, hash) => {
    db.query(
      "INSERT INTO `accounts`(`firstName`, `lastName`, `username`, `password`, `email`, `phone`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)",
      [firstName, lastName, username, hash, email, phone],
      (err, result) => {
        console.log(err);
        console.log(result);
      }
    );
  });
});

app.get("/login", (req, res) => {
  if (req.session.user) {
    res.send({ loggedIn: true, user: req.session.user });
  } else {
    res.send({ loggedIn: false });
  }
});

app.post("/login", (req, res) => {
  const email = req.body.email;
  const password = req.body.password;

  let sql = `SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE email="${email}"`;
  db.query(sql, (err, result) => {
    try {
      bcrypt.compare(password, result[0].password, (err, compResult) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        if (compResult) {
          req.session.user = result;
          res.send(compResult);
        } else if (!compResult) {
          res.send({ message: "Incorrect Password or Email!" });
        }
      });
    } catch (err) {
      res.send({ message: "Email does not exist!" });
    }
  });
});
```

Let me know if there is anything else you need!

Comment: The code *looks* like it shouldn't be sending a wildcard. Maybe you had `*` before, changed it, but didn't restart the server afterwards?

Comment: No, I have tried to restart the server multiple times but gives no result. I am using an API from `RapidAPI` (to be specific, the ASOS API). Though, in the same file where I am fetching the data, I tried to add: `Axios.defaults.withCredentials`, but instead of setting it to true, set it to false. It seems to work, but I am not 100% sure what it even does, will it mess up anything with my login/register stuff? @Quentin

Comment: Turning credentials support off means it is a simple request instead of a preflighted request, which allows `*` but doesn't allow cookies.

Comment: Ahhh okay, and of my understanding. Cookies in my situation are kind of my "session" right? (only worked with Flask and register forms in the past, much simpler there haha).

So I technically don't want it to be false? Or doesn't it really matter? It is a school project so only my teacher will be using this.

Comment: Cookies (in your example) are used to link a logged in browser with a collection of data on the server. If they aren't accepted and sent back then the login system won't work. It will go "You've logged in!" and then forget who you are on the next page.

Comment: Ahh, okay. So setting the value to false is most likely not a good idea, as it would just log me out automatically.

Comment: Is there a way around this tho? @Quentin

Comment: As I said, I don't understand why the problem is occurring in the first place.

Comment: Ah, okay my bad. Yea I never really understood what CORS really is. I guess I just have to go on a google spree and see if I can locate the problem. Thanks tho!